# Puppeteer - Why is modal hidden when emulating mobile device

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am currently trying to automate a scenario where a non-filtered search is performed on a car sales webpage. which has a cookies modal when first loaded. My issue is that when I run the script to emulate a mobile device the modal is hidden but the webpage is non responsive which implies the modal is either in the background or out of the screen.

Has anyone had something of a similar issue that could help

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const iPad = puppeteer.devices['iPad Pro'];

(async function()  {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless : false,
        slowMo: 50,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: ['--start-maximized'] 
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.emulate(iPad);
    await page.goto('https://www.arnoldclark.com/').catch();
}) ();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]? We cannot help with code we cannot see

Comment: Did you inspect the modal in the devtools of the Puppeteer browser? What did you find?

Comment: I haven't no but now that I have I see this <style type="text/css">
  .cookie-banner { display: none; }
  .ccc-notify-buttons > button > span,
  #ccc-button-holder > button > span { display: initial; }
</style> and <script src="https://cc.cdn.civiccomputing.com/9/cookieControl-9.x.min.js"></script>